# EditText drawableStart disappears on text change

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, drawable

I've got an EditText like the one in the image

[image: search edit]

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_station_et"
        style="@style/TextView.Secondary"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_station_search_edit"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/search"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/enter_station_hint_string"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:inputType="textShortMessage" />
```

I used the drawableStart to place the search icon and looks okey with the hint message.The problem is that when some text is entered in the field the drawable disappears.

Is there a way to keep the drawable visible on text changes?

Comment: Where is you code?

Comment: I added the xml code but the functional code is redundant in this case

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your code for better understanding?

And hope you're using this to add an image in your EditText

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dell"
```

Comment: android:drawablePadding="8dp"
What this line is meant to do ?

Comment: it's the padding for the drawable...applies some white space between the drawable and the text

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
android:inputType="textShortMessage"
```

to

```
android:inputType="text"
```

also add below property in xml

```
android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/search"
```

Comment: what is your `style/TextView.Secondary`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 3 years since the OP, but I came across what I think to believe the same bug (yes, I believe this is a bug) today.

It appears that, if the resource `drawableStart` is pointing to is also referenced somewhere else, the icon in the EditText disappears. I don't understand the root cause, but this seems to be the case.

Since you are referring to the `search` resource, try copying that resource, **give it a different name (this is very important)**, say `search2`, and instead of `android:drawableStart="@mipmap/search"` try using `android:drawableStart="@mipmap/search2`" and see if that works.